# Using a message endpoint to trigger a single select against a table

Tags: spring-integration

Our application uses a `jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter` to poll a database.

The new requirements specify that the upstream system will send a message to our application, and that this message will start the polling operation.

In some instances, the message will contain the parameters which the poller should use for the SELECT. (Currently the parameters are retrieved using the `select-sql-parameter-source` on the poller). In this case, our application will not really be be polling, but rather doing a single select against the datasource based on the message parameters.

What is the best way of integrating a message endpoint and a poller?

Also, if the poller is not suited for doing a single one-off select against the source table, what would be the appropriate Spring Integration component to use instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Such a scenario is called `event-driven`. For this purpose you can use `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>`.

What is interest you can utilze that from the generic `<int:inbound-channel-adapter>` to build the static message for `polling` case. Hence you won't have a duplication of code, because both events will use the same endpoint.

**UPDATE**

Let's imaging we have something like this:

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway request-channel="selectChannel" 
      query="select * from bazz where id=:payload"/>
```

So, you can send message with some `id` as a `payload` to that `selectChannel` manually, from `<gateway>`, or any other inbound adapter for an external system, e.g. `<int-http:inbound-gateway>`

Since you have a requirement to `poll` the same SELECT you can overcome it with something like this:

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter expression="'foo'" channel="selectChannel">
   <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

And the result of that `expression` will be send to the `selectChannel` on each `poll`.

Comment: Artem, thanks. I wonder if you could expand on your second point - it's not clear to me what you mean.

Comment: Added sample to the answer.